# Path changing when calling streamwriter?

Tags: c#, string, path, directory, streamwriter

So, I have the following three lines of c# code:

```
string pageAnnotationTextFilePath = currentPagePath.Substring(0, currentPagePath.Length-4) + ".txt";
print (pageAnnotationTextFilePath);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pageAnnotationTextFilePath, false);
```

And when I run it, I first receive the following print message, representing the value of the string called pageAnnotationTextFilePath:

```
file://C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Accessible/Assets/IO/Books/A community of learners/king/pages/page1.txt
```

This is correct, and as it should be. But then, the next line in the program gives me the error below. It seems that what is happening is that my path is being altered by the StreamWriter initialization class -- resulting in the project's location being appended to the first part of the path I provided. Why is it doing this, and why would it do this? The path that I'm referring to here in the stack trace is right at the top, here:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Accessible\file:\C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Accessible\Assets\IO\Books\A community of learners\king\pages\page1.txt".
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options)
System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
AnnotationIO+<SaveAllObjectDataToTextFile>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/AnnotationIO.cs:27)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
<SaveDataToBooksFolder>c__Iterator6:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/GUI/WizardAnnotationGUI.cs:81)
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
<AutoSave>c__Iterator5:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/GUI/WizardAnnotationGUI.cs:71)
```

Thanks for your expertise!

Comment: What is `currentPagePath` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hint

'Could not find a part of the path "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Accessible\file:\C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Accessible\Assets\IO\Books\A community of learners\king\pages\page1.txt"'

and notice that your print out is

'file://C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Accessible/Assets/IO/Books/A community of learners/king/pages/page1.txt'

So, you are feeding this string to StreamWriter. StreamWriter is taking this string and using it as a relative path. Your working directory must be:

'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Accessible\'

The two are getting appended to each other. Long story short, you have to strip out the "file://"

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense. Thanks. I guess I'm curious about why it would even do that -- but alas, greater minds than mine have already divined that this is the way.